# How to handle implicit broadcast in background on android oreo through jobScheduler

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

As we know From Android Oreo google has restricted background services and broadcast. Many people are saying we can use jobScheduler in place of services. But i am unable to find any solution to handle implicit broadcast in background. Suppose i want handle `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` in my app. i can register this action dynamically when app is foreground. but is that any way to listen same broadcast when app is in background. or any suggestion to achieve this.Thanks!!

Comment: have look [Exploring Background Execution Limits on Android Oreo](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c)

Comment: Have you find any solution? i also have same problem

Answer (score 3):

Pasting the line from android [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts)

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts **in their manifest.**

- Apps can use `Context.registerReceiver()` at runtime to register a
  receiver for any broadcast, *whether implicit or explicit*.

Which states that, you can still receive implicit broadcast at runtime, *if you are managing your app to be run in background*.

Additionally,
Here is the link about some tricks to make your app, run in a background:

[Migrate an app to Android Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#migration)